# memcpy to av_malloc's memory crash

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I use the code in x64 windows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>
#include<vector>
extern "C"
{
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include<libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include<libswscale/swscale.h>
#include<libswresample/swresample.h>
}

struct BufferData
{
    uint8_t* ptr;
    size_t size;
    size_t file_size;
};

int main()
{
    auto file=fopen("E:/test.jpg", "rb");
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    auto fileSize = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    auto data = std::vector<uint8_t>(fileSize);
    fread(data.data(), sizeof(uint8_t), fileSize, file);
    fclose(file);

    auto test = BufferData();
    test.ptr = data.data();
    test.size = data.size();
    test.file_size = data.size();
    auto buffer = (uint8_t*)av_malloc(4096 * 10);
    char errStr[128] = { 0 };

    auto avformatContext = avformat_alloc_context();
    auto avioContext = avio_alloc_context(buffer, 4096, 0, &test, [](void* opaque, uint8_t* buf, int buf_size)
        {
            BufferData* bd = (BufferData*)opaque;
            auto size = std::min(bd->size, (size_t)buf_size);

            if (!size)
            {
                return -1;
            }

            memcpy(buf, bd->ptr, size);
            bd->ptr += size;
            bd->size -= size;
            return (int)size;
        }, NULL, NULL);
    avformatContext->pb = avioContext;
    avformatContext->flags = AVFMT_FLAG_CUSTOM_IO;

    auto ret = avformat_open_input(&avformatContext, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        av_strerror(ret, errStr, sizeof(errStr));
        std::cout << errStr << std::endl;
        av_free(buffer);
        avformat_close_input(&avformatContext);
        return 0;
    }

    ret = avformat_find_stream_info(avformatContext, nullptr);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        av_strerror(ret, errStr, sizeof(errStr));
        std::cout << errStr << std::endl;
        av_free(buffer);
        avformat_close_input(&avformatContext);
        return 0;
    }

    av_dump_format(avformatContext, 0, nullptr, 0);

    auto videoIndex = av_find_best_stream(avformatContext, AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, -1, -1, nullptr, 0);
    if (videoIndex == AVERROR_STREAM_NOT_FOUND)
    {
        av_free(buffer);
        avformat_close_input(&avformatContext);
        return 0;
    }
    else if (videoIndex == AVERROR_DECODER_NOT_FOUND)
    {
        av_free(buffer);
        avformat_close_input(&avformatContext);
        return 0;
    }

    auto videoCodecPar = avformatContext->streams[videoIndex]->codecpar;
    auto videoCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(videoCodecPar->codec_id);
    if (!videoCodec)
    {
        av_free(buffer);
        avformat_close_input(&avformatContext);
        return 0;
    }

    av_free(buffer);
    avformat_close_input(&avformatContext);
}
```

I use memcpy to copy data to buffer,it run to av_free(buffer) get crash.
ffmpeg version is 6.0.
Visual Studio version is 2022 with CMake.

Use fread replace memcpy,it can work!But I need to resolve load from std::vector<uint8_t> memory,not fread.
I think maybe memory-align problem when run av_free,but I no way to find the cause.

Comment: As the documentation (and example) says, the buffer may have been reallocated. The actual current buffer that you need to release is `avioContext->buffer`.

Comment: You right.buffer's address not equal `avioContext->buffer`'s.It works!
Maybe I need to read all ffmepg documentation and example.Thank you!